# How to setup loading of my dll that depends on some thirdparty dll by env-variable?

Tags: c++, dll

Eg: I have C:\test\foo.exe that requires my bar.dll (which in turn requires baz.dll, assuming baz.dll is not a standard windows shared component), then I'm placing both bar.dll and baz.dll in C:\test dialog and everyting is working.

But I want everyting to be in its place, so I want to avoid procedure of coping all dependent dll's into same folder as my C:\test\foo.exe. E.g. I want to set some env variable that will store path to directory where baz.dll is situated, and then use it to load libraries.

Is it possible? How can it be done? What is your way of dealing with such situation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your app is linked. I assume like most modern apps you're creating it with an assembly manifest which creates a load context. If not, then DLLs will be found on %PATH%, so you can use that. However, read on if you're using a manifest:

In most cases, to find a DLL in an arbitrary location, you'll have to dynamically load your dependencies using `LoadLibrary`; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya

Longer answer: there's no built-in way to do this. It would be a security hole because it would allow an attacker to replace DLLs with their own. But assuming your application isn't concerned with this, you can use `LoadLibrary` to load your bar.dll (finding it using whatever method you like); you'll have to replace all the calls to functions in that DLL with function pointers that you resolve at runtime using `GetProcAddress` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress).

Now as for the secondary dependency baz.dll, I *think* if you load it with `LoadLibrary` first, when you then load bar.dll, it will resolve its dependencies against the already-loaded baz.dll.

If you really want to get complicated, you can wrap your dependent DLLs in an assembly; the assembly itself can specify paths, I believe. But this gets pretty hairy.